# confused by Windows Run Time Component Directories and which .winmd file do I need to add

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I create a WindowsRuntimeComponent3 solution, batch build

[image]

[image]

then VS create a series directories as below, there are WindowsRuntimeComponent3.winmd in these different directories.

just wonder which WindowsRuntimeComponent3.winmd do I need to add?

[image]

if them one by one, it will report error

[image]

your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a reference to the project directly, and VS will take care of the CPU architecture and build flavour for you; you shouldn't need to look in those specific directories. When you add the reference, choose "Projects" instead of "Assemblies."