# try to create a c++/winrt componet and add a reference to a UWP app, but failed

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Try to create a c++/winrt component and add a reference to a UWP app, but failed.

Below is what I did:

**1. create c++/WinRT component**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2. create a c# UWP app project**

[image]

[image]

**3.in the c# UWP project, add the former c++/WinRT component to reference**

[image]

[image]

[image]

it always reports the error as below (I try to add Component1.solution, Component1.vcxproj with same error result)

[image]

your comment welcome

Comment: You must select the .winmd file that's generated by the component project.  That's the metadata file ("type library" is old speak) that describes the component.  A walkthrough [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/create-a-windows-runtime-component-in-cppwinrt)

Comment: in another thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401859/confused-by-windows-run-time-component-directories-and-which-winmd-file-do-i-ne  somebody said: When you add the reference, choose "Projects" instead of "Assemblies."

Comment: Hmm, that can only work if you put the projects in the same solution.  Doesn't look like you did.  Recover with File > Add > Existing Project.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I found the file 'Component1.winmd' located at folder 'ARM\Component1\Component1.winmd' 'ARM64\Component1\Component1.winmd' 'debug\Component1\Component1.winmd' 'release\Component1\Component1.winmd' 'x64\Component1\Component1.winmd', do I need to add them one by one under the different plateform?

Comment: @Hans Passan, I mean that there are 8 Component1.winmd files, how can I add reference suitable related platform? what I can do is add one Component1.winmd, only works for one platform and reports an error when I switch to another platform

Comment: I got the info here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019 to add the different target platform, thanks, if you like, please set your comment as an answer, I will accept it